# How to extract checkbox data into another page in PHP (checkbox data is populated from MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, extract

i have created a list of checkbox data which has been populated with values from mysql database. Now i would like to extract the selected checkbox data into another page "functions_two.php" when clicked submit. i can't seem to figure out a way to do this as the checkbox data has been taken from the database.

below is my updated code:

```
<?PHP

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$databaseName = "my computer";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



?>


<html>  
<body>


<form name="aform" action="functions_two.php" method="POST">


<div id="collegelane">College Lane campus:</div>


<?php


$q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }

?>

</div>

</br>
</br>


<div id="dehav">De Havilland campus:</div>


<?php
$q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus_two`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }

?>


</br>
</br>


<div id="next"><input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/></div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

the functions_two.php page code is below:

```
<html>  
<body>


<?php

$carchecked = $_POST['car'];
foreach ($carchecked as $cars){
      echo $cars."<br />";

}


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Checkbox name attribute must be the same for all checkboxes for each while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a.= '<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" 
        value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
```

So you get the data in functions_two.php

```
$carchecked = $_POST['car'];
foreach ($carchecked as $cars){
      echo $cars."<br />";

}
```

Since your are using mysqli_connect, the procedural way of connecting mysql database, your query must be as follow:

```
    $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }
```

You don't need such things at all: $s = ''; $j = 0; $a = ''; $b = 0;.

Comment: hi, i updated my code as you said, however i still don't get any outputs??... you can see my updated code above

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i get an empty page when i select the checkboxes and press submit

Comment: i get no error message so i dnt know whats wrong

Comment: add this code at the top `print_r($_POST['car'])` to make sure you get the checked cars.

Comment: hi, i still get no output?

Comment: Please check the online demo [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xcwy-gcpb). This will give you how it works.